# Search for file, if not there then download

Tags: c#, file, webclient

How would I search for a file (in the current directory the exe is running in) and if it is not found, it will download it?
I already know how to do the downloading part, WebClient.DownloadFile("link.com","link.exe");

TL;DR:
How would I search for a file in the directory (link.exe) and if it is not there, download it?

Comment: What did you try?

You want to
1. Know the location of which directory you currently are in
2. Check if there is a specific file in that location.
3. if not you want to download the file

Comment: Do you need help finding the current exe's folder, or to actually check for the file's presence in that folder?

Comment: I need help checking for the files presence in the current folder. I already have the current folder located.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the full path where the file should be located, you can simply call `System.IO.File.Exists(thePath)`, which will return either `true` or `false`.

Note that `thePath` must be the full path to the file, not to the folder.

Or do you need something else?

Comment: so would the syntax be like: if (System.IO.File.Exists(currentpath\test.exe == false))
                {

                }

Comment: I'm sorry, but programming is not a guessing game. Please fire up your web browser, and find the `File.Exists` method on MSDN. Stop guessing, read reference material.

Comment: Why do you think I came here?

Comment: Apparently to be spoon fed.

Answer (score 1):

You want to firstly find out which directory you are in. Then you want check whether the file exsist or not.

```
string file_location = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "link.exe";
if (File.Exists(file_location) == false)
{
   WebClient.DownloadFile("link.com", "link.exe");
}
```

Environment.CurrentDirectory:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx

File.Exists:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: May I suggest `if (!File.Exists(file_location))` instead? The method returns a bool, so testing against `false` is a bit redundant. Not bad in itself, just a matter of preference I guess.